# Codeigniter index page

Tags: codeigniter, uri

I want to create a page, which I will be able to browse like this: `/page/5`.

I have created a `page.php` controller and I can view this page, here is its content:

> class Page extends CI_Controller {
>
> ```
> public function __construct()
> {
>     parent::__construct();
> }
>
> public function index()
> {
>     $this->load->view('template/header');
>
>     $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
>     $this->load->view('template/middle', array('id' => $id));
>     $this->load->view('template/footer');
> }
> ```
>
> }

The problem is that I cant reach the page number from the uri.

To be clear:

This is reachable: `index.php/page`.

But at this url, I'm getting the 404: `index.php/page/5`

I know I can make another controller function to view the page like this `/index.php/page/id/5`, but I want it be be accessable via the index function.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't know whether you're looking for **5()** or **index(5)**

To fix this, Try setting up a custom route in **config/routes.php**:

```
$route['page/(:num)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Also, In your index function:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/middle', array('id' => $id));
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you :-). What is the difference of using `public function index(*$id*)` and `$id = $this->uri->segment(2);`?

Comment: No problem, Well you could still use segments, I just think that arguments are fancier :P

Comment: if you do `public function index($id)`, you HAVE to pass in an id like this page/index/1. if you try to access page/index, it will not work.

Comment: @Catfish He can still make it optional: `index($id=false)`

Comment: I know, but he asked what the difference was between `index($id)` and the `$this->uri->segment()` so i was just trying to clarify.

Comment: shouldn't it be $this->uri->segment(3); to get the first parameter passed to function? I always get first parameter to function with segment(3)